# Is it possible to implement SSO in a ReactJs application with SAML2? if possible how?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am new to this field and have a lot of confusions, in this case, I have to implement single sign-on in a ReactJs application where it's back-end is node express using OKTA as the IDP?

Please share your thoughts.

Thank you

Comment: It would better if you could ask a more direct, specific question relating to your code so that we can reproduce it and help to solve the _problem_ you're facing. Questions like these are better suited to a discussion, rather than on a question/answering platform

Comment: Hi, My question is can we implement SSO on react application with SAML2?

Comment: You're asking whats the *best possible way* to implement it. Your question implies that you already know it's possible, but that you're asking which way is the 'best' way. These leaves the question open for discussion, primarily around opinion etc.

Comment: @GBWDev I have edited the question if you know the answer, please let me know ?

Comment: Is OpenID Connect an option? https://developer.okta.com/quickstart-fragments/react/default-example/

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying your ReactJS application using express, you can use passport-saml for managing your saml workflow.

The basic idea should be to serve up your app only if you recieve a valid saml response from the idp.

You can check more here : [passport-saml](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml/)

Answer (score 0):

If u are using your react app without express, you can connect your okta app directly to your react sdk with open idc (okta has an option for this).